# Помогите пожалуйста кто знает

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
>   GET, HEAD.

Это мой код для ajax запроса, в web.php я сделал Route:post ;

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/user/edit",
    method: "post",
    data: {
        '_token': Token,
        id,
    },
    success: function(r){
        // console.log(r)
    }
})
```

Comment: @u_mulder хз на вопрос в принципе можно ответить, что он в роуте не поставил пост метод, но вот слово помагите просто режет глаза и кровь из ушей идет от него

Comment: Привет user372744, не запаривайся на счёт минусов, Но  лучше, больше не пиши в заглавии слова не относящиеся к вопросу напрямую. Вот тебе лайк от меня!)

Comment: я поставил в роуте, я не дебил что просто так писал Route::post !
вот мой код ->  Route::post('/user/edit', "productController@edit")

Comment: а сейчас дает эту ошибку, но у меня все скрипты поставлены и jQuery тоже работает нормально, но пишет что ajax is not function
Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (user:205)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, нужно так:

Для GET:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/user/edit",
    method: "get",
    data: {
        '_token': Token,
        id,
    },
    success: function(r){
        // console.log(r)
    }
})
```

Для HEAD:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/user/edit",
    method: "head",
    data: {
        '_token': Token,
        id,
    },
    success: function(r){
        // console.log(r)
    }
})
```